# How do I redirect users after submitting a topic for moderation?

Tags: redirect, bbpress, moderation

I'm using bbPress (Version 2.5.3) with the plugin bbPress Moderation (Version 1.8.3) on WordPress 3.8.1.

After a user submits a new topic for moderation, the forum shows up again without the new question, and with no explanation that the question is awaiting moderation.  Can I redirect the user to another URL with an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Modify the file "form-topic.php" (located in "/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/templates/default/bbpress/form-topic.php"):

```
32  <form id="new-post" name="new-post" method="post" 
    action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Change it to:

```
32  <form id="new-post" name="new-post" method="post" 
    action="<?php echo the_permalink() . "?redirect_to=/question-awaiting-moderation/"; ?>">
```

Upload this modified file to: "/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/bbpress/form-topic.php"

Do the same for the replies if you are moderating those (form-reply.php).